# Cucumber Stopping Execution after Time in Steps

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-java

One of my tests waits until an event happens in the `Then` step. If the test works fine there is no issue but if the test is failing (i.e. no event is triggered) then it just hangs.

How can I set a timeout in `Cucumber`?

I know `JUnit` has a timeout parameter you can use in the [`@Test annotation`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Test.html), is there something similar for `Cucumber`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Cucumber` has followed the `JUnit` pattern and offers a **`timeout`** parameter in its steps annotations. This takes a long value specifying the number of milliseconds after which the step is failed if it doesn't finish execution.

You can use it as follows:

```
@Then(value = "^verify (\\d+) events sent$", timeout = 5000)
```

This also works on the other step types (e.g. `Given`, `When`).

Don't forget to add `value =` before the steps definition string.

Comment: does this work?  I tried a simple example and it doesn't seem to fail the test

Comment: @jcalloway it does for me. Why not ask a stackoverflow question with your code example, link it here and we can have a look?

Comment: Note that since Cucumber-JVM 5.x this is no longer available - see "Removing timeout" section of https://cucumber.io/blog/open-source/announcing-cucumber-jvm-v5-0-0-rc1/