# Unable to set timeout for cucumber steps in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

currently we have our test-steps implemented via

`io.cucumber.java.en.Then;`

`@Then("do something")`

after some resarch i found, that you should be able to add a step-timeout like this:

`@Then(value = "do something", timeout = 5000)`

But this is not possible (cannot resolve method timeout)

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: *"...i found, that you should be able to add a step-timeout..."* Where did you find it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456589/cucumber-stopping-execution-after-time-in-steps

Comment: You might want to check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456589/cucumber-stopping-execution-after-time-in-steps#comment109219531_47456590) posted to that same answer. It seems [that option was removed](https://cucumber.io/blog/open-source/announcing-cucumber-jvm-v5-0-0-rc1/).

Comment: You can write your on function to do this. All you need to do is update your step definition method to take one additional (`int`) parameter and handle this yourself. I have done it many times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cucumber Stopping Execution after Time in Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456589/cucumber-stopping-execution-after-time-in-steps)

Comment: @hfontanez wouldn't it be more pratctial to overwrite the original Method (Then/ When...) ?

Comment: @Tobi that's what I meant when I said "write your own function." Just pass an _int_ parameter and handle the timeout yourself. I have done this many times.

Comment: @Lynxi No, that doesn't answer the question. In fact, the question the OP is asking is why that precise link doesn't work for him. User lealcedeiro pointed out that in the comment section of that linked answer, it was mention that this notation is no longer supported. In the future, please be more careful when suggest a question to be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In the question linked in the comments as a possible solution to this issue, it was posted that "*since Cucumber-JVM 5.x this is no longer available*." The link given as a reference is https://cucumber.io/blog/open-source/announcing-cucumber-jvm-v5-0-0-rc1/ ***Removing Timeout*** section.

In the past, I have used the following pattern to implement handling of timeouts on my end.

1. Create a step that takes an additional parameter (int) to specify the timeout to be used.
2. Create a base-case step to use a default timeout. From here, I call the method created in step 1 above, passing a default timeout value.

Basically, I use ***Method Overloading*** to handle this.

```
// specific timeout case
@When("I do something {int}")
public void doSomething(int timeout) {
    // do whatever
}

// base (default) case
@When("I do something")
public void doSomething() {
    doSomething(500);
}
```

This should be very simple to implement and you should be able to use your existing method by simply removing the `timeout` parameter inside the `@When` tag.

Comment: I do not want to set the timeout in the stepdefinition. I want a general timeout for all my steps.. so this is not the solution. But Thanks!

Comment: @Tobi What you want is not supported anymore. This is one solution that works around that lack of native support.